# update statement with select and case in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm facing a problem when I try to execute update statement In SQL Server 2012:

```
update ScmInOutD 
    set QtyValue= (select case when ScmInOutMas.InOutType ='I' or  ScmInOutMas.InOutType ='B' then Qty else Qty*-1 end  Qty
from 
    ScmInOutMas,ScmInOutD where ScmInOutD.InOutID = ScmInOutMas.InOutID)
```

Error Msg Show To me:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: You have a phantom alias at the end of the SET line "Qty" (after the "end")

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Your subquery returns more than 1 value...which one should it use? Also, you should update to use the ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around for almost 30 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Looks like you need to wrap your case inside a SUM aggregate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `JOIN` in `UPDATE` statement

```
update SD
set SD.QtyValue= (case when  SM.InOutType ='I'  or  SM.InOutType ='B'  then Qty else Qty*-1  end)
FROM ScmInOutD SD
JOIN ScmInOutMas SM ON SD.InOutID = SM.InOutID
```